# Building a call tree for a Python code

Tags: python, function, call-graph

I've been given a Python code, together with the  modules it imports. I would like to build a tree indicating which function calls what other functions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) (abstract syntax tree) module from the python standard library

```
# foo.py
def func(x):
    print('hello')
```

parsing the file using `ast.parse`:

```
import ast
tree = ast.parse(open('foo.py').read())
print(ast.dump(tree))  # dumps the whole tree

# get the function from the tree body (i.e. from the file's content)
func = tree.body[0]

# get the function argument names
arguments = [a.arg for a in func.args.args]
print('the functions is: %s(%s)' % (func.name, ', '.join(arguments)))
```

outputs:

```
"Module(body=[FunctionDef(name='func', args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='x', annotation=None)], vararg=None, kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s='hello')], keywords=[]))], decorator_list=[], returns=None)])"

the functions is: func(x)
```

Comment: Looks interesting! I'm not sure how to use it, though. If tomorrow I modify my question adding a minimal example, could you show me how to use `ast` to build the corresponding call tree?

Comment: Hmm, the output seems too verbose to be of any help. It seems to include also all the statements inside each function, not just the calls. On a code thousand lines long, with numerous dependencies,  I don't think it will generate usable output. Is it possible to limit the output to the function calls? Tomorrow I'll add a minimal example, with input and desired output.

Comment: the `ast.dump(tree)` only prints nicely the tree for debugging proposes. you can access the tree members and attributes. I added example of getting the function name and arguments

Answer (score 2):

You should begin from the main function of the program and at the first layer link all functions that are called from the main this would provide a start point and then you can link all the functions below it.